# Store.sync() lose extraParams

Tags: extjs5

I have treeStore with extraParams

```
proxy: {
   extraParams: {hierarchy_id: '5'},
   api: {   
      update: jsonrpc.dim_hier.modifyData,
      read: jsonrpc.dim_hier.getData,
      create: jsonrpc.dim_hier.addData,
      destroy: jsonrpc.dim_hier.deleteData
  }
}
```

but store.sync() does not send to server this extraParams.
I tried to send param like this

```
component.getStore().getProxy().setExtraParam(  
 'hierarchy_id', hierarchy_id);
component.getStore().sync();
```

and this

```
component.getStore().sync({
  params :{
    hierarchy_id: hierarchy_id}
});
```

and

```
component.getStore().getProxy().setExtraParams({
  hierarchy_id: hierarchy_id
});
component.getStore().sync();
```

but none of this works

What did I do wrong?
Thank for any help

Answer (score 0):

In method doRequest (Ext.data.proxy.Direct)

```
if (action === 'read') {  
  params = request.getParams();        
} else {          
  params = request.getJsonData();        
}
```

I override this method like this

```
params = request.getParams();
if (action !== 'read') {            
  params.rows = request.getJsonData();        
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
var store = component.getStore();
Ext.apply(store.proxy, {
    extraParams: {
        hierarchy_id: hierarchy_id
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**TO SEND THE extraParams ALWAYS NOT ONLY ON READ OPERATIONS (CREATE, DESTROY, UPDATE)**

I extended

> Ext.data.proxy.Direct

and override

> doRequest

It worked like a charm.

Using ExtJs 4.1.1

The original code is:

```
if (operation.action == 'read') {
            // We need to pass params
            method = fn.directCfg.method;
            args = method.getArgs(params, me.paramOrder, me.paramsAsHash);
        } else {
            args.push(request.jsonData);
        }
```

I changed it to:

```
    method = fn.directCfg.method;
    args = method.getArgs(params, me.paramOrder, me.paramsAsHash);

    if(operation.action !== 'read'){
         args.push(request.jsonData);
    }
```

Took the idea from here https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?282879-ExtraParams-Store-Create

**Notice**: your store will have a proxy of whatever you put on the alias of the class you created. Your alias will be like `alias : 'proxy.mycompanydirect'` then your store will have a proxy type `'mycompanydirect'`